# Nativescript angular WebView - "Cannot start http server for devtools"

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to get a WebView working for our angular Nativescript app. Unfortunately, I get a blank white screen the following error when trying to load the webview in an emulator that is connected to the internet (`tns run android --bundle`):

`JS: WebView<plaid-webview>
chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(36)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
02-26 14:52:07.826 12754 12754 I cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=false
chromium: [ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(292)] Cannot start http server for devtools. Stop devtools.`

Here is the component html:

```
<StackLayout>
    <WebView #plaidWebview id="plaid-webview" [src]="plaidWebviewSrc"> 
    </WebView>
</StackLayout>
```

And in the component ts (component.tns.ts), I set the src:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'plaid-webview',
  templateUrl: './plaid-webview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./plaid-webview.component.scss']
})
export class PlaidWebViewComponent implements OnInit {

public plaidWebViewSrc : string = "https://docs.nativescript.org/";
...
```

This matches the documentation [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/web-view)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before, but the webview is now loading the url correctly. I still get the devtools error, but I'm not overly concerned by it. If someone has a solution for that, feel free to post it and I'll mark as the solution.